# Lib Xml Ruby :Error `parse': undefined method `read' for "file.xml":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, libxml2, libxml-ruby

```
require 'xml/libxml'
require 'libxml/document'
$release_date
doc=LibXML::XML::Parser.io(file.xml).parse 
doc.root.each_element('//ABCD/xyz/') do |elem|
    elem.each_element do |node|             
        node.each_element do |child|
           if child.content=="ABCD"
               $release_date=node['date']
           else 
               if node['type']=="Original"
                   $release_date=node['date']
               end
           end  
        end    
    end 
end
puts "Release date : #{$release_date}"
```

This is the code that I've written to extract a particular date from an XML file according to my requirements. I've used lib xml library but am getting the following errors:

```
`parse': undefined method `read' for "file.xml":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: `LibXML::XML::Parser.io(File.open("file.xml").parse`

Comment: file = File.open("filename.xml")
doc=LibXML::XML::Parser.io(file).parse                              Still getting error:                                      `each_element': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Comment: That’s because `each_element` does not take any parameter: http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Node.html#M000252

Comment: https://github.com/amolpujari/reading-huge-xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [libxml documentation](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Parser.html), to parse a file:

```
LibXML::XML::Parser.file('file.xml').parse
```

or

```
LibXML::Parser.io(File.open('file.xml')).parse
```

Also, `each_element` [doesn’t take any parameter](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Node.html#M000252).  If you want to do an XPath query, have a look at [find](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Document.html#M000475):

```
require 'xml'
doc = LibXML::XML::Parser.file("/tmp/test.xml").parse 
nodes = doc.find('//test')
nodes.each do |n|
  puts n.content
end
```

Comment: In this line  :doc.root.each_element('//ABCD/xyz/') abcd,xyz are all nodes and thats how I need to traverse. So could you guide me how do I traverse ? Tried using find it gave an error. If i work like this  root='//ABCD/XYX/'
doc.root.each_element() do |elem|                                    am not getting any error but it gives me the following output (no date is printed): release date:

Comment: @Aayush I have updated my answer to give an example – as I said, everything is in the documentation.  Regarding your other issue, make sure you don’t have a trailing slash.  Do `doc.find("//ABCD/XYZ")`